# Missing key value on 'GradientStopCollection' object, but there's clearly a key attached?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have some XAML code that looks like the following:

```
<Style x:Key="DigitalClockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WPFSoundVisualizationLib:DigitalClock}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type WPFSoundVisualizationLib:DigitalClock}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <GradientStopCollection x:Key="SegmentGradient">
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource MainAccent}" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource SubAccent}" Offset="1" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>

                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DigitBrush" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" GradientStops="{StaticResource SegmentGradient}" />
                    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="EmptyBrush" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1" Opacity="0.1" GradientStops="{StaticResource SegmentGradient}" />
                    ....
```

For some reason, this code gives the error "Missing key value on 'GradientStopCollection' object" in the editor, but compiles completely as if the error didn't exist. The style works when compiled, but in the editor the ENTIRE file has a red line under it, and the XAML designer doesn't work.

I've tried resetting Visual Studio (2013), I've re-installed, cleaned and rebuilt the solution, tried on two different machines and nothing fixes it. The XAML itself works fine but the 'error' stops the designer from displaying anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: this is one of the most annoying bugs of XAML editor. You can try ***cutting and re-pasting*** the snippet `GradientStopCollection`. Note that after cutting, please wait to see if the error is gone, then re-paste it. If it still notifies error. Try cutting and save the file, restart visual studio and re-paste it.

Comment: I tried both methods you said, neither of them worked. If this is a XAML editor bug then I'm really surprised it hasn't been fixed already.